# Unity 2D drag and drop without using Canvas

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop

I have a board that made with bunch of square tiles, i have player which is circle and i wanna  drop over the tiles and set plater postion to the center of nearest tile while mouse button up ;
is there any way to handle this without Canvas and EventSystem ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do it,

You can store all the tiles in an array and when dragging the player check for the position of the closest one, this can work great if you have gaps between tiles and want the player to still snap on to the tile even if the player is not over it by having a threshold setup, it could get a bit costly though if you have thousands of tiles and you are iterating through them all.

Second and the easiest one is to just cast a Raycast from your player straight to the plane where your tiles are positioned, on hit just position the player in the middle of the tile. If you have more objects in the scene you can also tag the tiles with for example "Tile" and in the raycast check for the tag. The use of raycasts is documented here https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html

Comment: Tank you :) , I saw something aboute Physics.Raycast that is this function uses only for 3d object and its coliders so  is it work for 2d game objects ?

Comment: Yes you're right, you are going to need colliders but for square tiles it should be very straightforward. When it comes to 2d, Unity 2d workspace is nothing but a 3d space with an ability for you to change the (usually Z) value for the player to that higher than the tiles and then cast the raycast from it downwards.